# Permission error when using mmap to modify a file

Tags: c, linux

Created a simple mmap program that modifies a byte file. 
Run it as root on a simple/small file, got error

```
# ./a.out tmp.txt 92
fd=3
mmap: Permission denied
```

Code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY);
    printf("fd=%d\n", fd);
    char *p = mmap(0, 0x1000, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror ("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    p[0] = 0xde;
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Wonder what went wrong.  Thanks.

**UPDATE1**
Fixed a typo in the code snippet, I meant to use `PROT_WRITE` there.

Comment: Thanks @mch for pointing out, I corrected the code snippet by using `PROT_WRITE` but got the same story.

Comment: Is the size of the file really `0x1000` bytes? That are 4096 bytes.

Comment: The size is actually 92 bytes, used `0x1000` because it's a page size on my Linux

Comment: What owner/user and permissions does tmp.txt have, and what user are you running the program as? `ls -l tmp.txt; id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the man page for mmap:

> **EACCES** A file descriptor refers to a non-regular file.  Or a file  mapping  was  requested,  but  fd  is  not  open  for  reading.  Or
>                 **MAP_SHARED** was requested and **PROT_WRITE** is set, but  fd  is  not
>                 open in read/write (**O_RDWR**) mode.  Or **PROT_WRITE** is set, but the
>                 file is append-only.

So in order to map a file **MAP_SHARED**, you need to open it in read/write mode, not writeonly.  Makes sense, as the contents of the file needs to be read to initialize parts of the memory you don't write.

In addition, IA-32 does not allow write-only mappings of pages, so mapping with `PROT_WRITE` on such a machine will implictly also enable `PROT_READ`, so will fail for a file descriptor that isn't readable.